# How to pgrep to find a bash script on macOS (or how to programatically kill a script running in the background)?

Tags: shell-script, grep, kill, background-process, macos

I'm trying to programatically kill a bash script running as a background process (on macOS). The way I've settled on for now is to `pgrep` the name of the script and then pass the PID value to a `kill` function.

*Note: If anyone has a better suggestion on how to do this please feel free to provide it.*

The problem I'm running into is that on macOS, the name of the process isn't just the name of the script, and instead appears to be `/bin/bash /Users/...../[scriptname]`. In addition, I can't `pgrep [scriptname]` to get the PID, I have to `pgrep bash` instead which often gives me more than one result.

Does anyone have a recommendation on either i) how I can use `pgrep` properly to `kill` this script or ii) whether there is a more obvious / cleaner way of doing this?

*Note: When I run the same script in Lubuntu, it doesn't have `/bin/bash` or the full directory as part of the name, and instead is just called `[scriptname]`. So `pgrep [scriptname]` works as intended.*

Comment: have you considered `killall`? Its purpose is to kill processes. Check `man killall`.

Comment: Does the macOS pgrep support `-f`? Can you find it with `pgrep -f scriptname`?

Comment: @terdon: Yes, macOS uses the BSD ver of `pgrep`, but it does support the `-f` option.

Comment: @terdon thank you, the `pgrep -f` works so long as I type in the entire path name e.g. `pgrep -f '/bin/bash /Users/.../[scriptname]'`. I will use this for now thank you.

Comment: On my Mac (Catalina), it seems to work fine with just the name of the script. If my answer didn't work for you, please let me know as I'd like to delete it if it doesn't work.

Comment: If you're using `pgrep`+`kill`, then you are much better off using `pkill` directly.

Comment: Thanks @Seamus, you are correct that with `pgrep -f` works with just the script name. My mistake for not having recognized that earlier.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes - macOS is very messy on this, but I think `pgrep` and `pkill` are a sound way to go about this:

```bsh
% pgrep -U 502 -f sleepforever.sh
43894
```

Some explanation may be in order:

- `-U 502` is my *real user id* gotten from `id`
- `sleepforever.sh` is a script I created to test this:

  ```bsh
  #!/bin/bash
  while :
  do
      sleep 10
  done
  ```

But all that `pgrep` can actually do is find the `pid`. To get the job done, use `pkill` - it shares many of the its arguments with `pgrep`:

```bsh
% pkill -U 502 -f sleepforever.sh
%
```